# Is VOTE a linking or an action verb?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence "Brianna was voted the co-captain" is "was voted" a linking or action verb phrase?
I believe it is action and "co-captain" is the direct object (co-captain as a title/position), but it is difficult to explain to students as they view it as Brianna = co-captain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57414/discussion-between-billj-and-araucaria-man).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the sentence into active you get: They voted Brianna co-captain with the structure verb, direct object, complement to direct object.

This is not the structure of a sentence like "My father is a teacher". So I wouldn't say "voted" is a linking verb.