# What's the sentence pattern of "I'm only one call away"

Tags: grammar

I found the sentence

> "I'm only one call away"

in the song lyric of "One call away - Charlie Puth" and got to have doubt about what its sentence pattern should be like? It's possible if it could be **S+V+O+C+A** pattern like this following sentence:

> "The governor / has sworn / him / chief minister / yesterday"

However it might be pretty incorrect that I would fit it in the SOVCA pattern. Because a word "one", in the former sentence, is not playing the role as object like "him", in the latter one, yet it's playing as subjective complement instead, right?
And, what is the part of speech of a word "call" in the song lyric? Is it noun?

Comment: Think of it like "I'm only 100 kilometers away."

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence doesn't have an object, so it doesn't fit into that pattern.

Compare:

- *I am smart.* (no object, *smart* is a complement)
- *I am away.* (no object, *away* is a complement)
- *I am two miles away.* (*away* is a complement which is modified by the noun phrase *two miles*)
- *I am one call away.* (same as above, *away* is modified by the noun phrase *one call*)

BTW, there are different views on what part of speech *away* is in the above sentence (adverb? preposition?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember ever coming across this shorthand sentence pattern notation before, but seems I am behind the times!

But if it's basically as suggested in this description at [Grammar In English](http://www.grammarinenglish.com/sentencepattern/), I hope I can help...

**I** is indeed the *subject*.  It's the one driving the sentence, the "who", and it's found in its common spot, ahead of the verb.

**am** is the *verb* (in the contraction form 'm).  It is the "activity" as it were.  With the subject, it would indeed make a sentence, albeit a pretty meaningless one, on its own: "I am".  And it appears to be acting as a [linking verb](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/linking_verbs.htm), as is verb typical of forms of the verb "to be".

I see **away** as the (primary) *complement*.  Indeed, it's important to note that linking verbs don't have true objects, as backed up my [Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm).

> Don't mistake a direct object for a subject complement.   **Only action** **verbs** can have direct objects. If the verb is linking, then the word
>   that answers the what? or who? question is a subject complement.

And then I would lean towards calling **only one call** an additional *[adjective complement](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/the-adjective-phrase-complement-in-english-grammar/)* (in this case modifying "away", the primary subject complement), because it seems to be important information in defining the complement.  It is describing the condition of the complement.

Had to look a bit to see what it would be called.  Thought maybe it was an adjunct, especially given they get [pretty complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)).  But definitely seemed to be important descriptive information about the complement, even before I came across the "adjective complement" term.

So I'd say **SVCC** is my best suggestion.

Comment: The only other option I could see is SVCA. "Away" can be [either adjective or adverb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/away). If it is acting as adverb, then it must "am", so "am" isn't a linking verb, but action. Seems a topic debated a lot such as in the comments to [this ESE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302491/linking-vs-action-verb), and comparing [this site](http://www.gallaudet.edu/tip/english-center/grammar-and-vocabulary/verbs/action-verbs-and-linking-verbs.html) vs [this site](http://www.really-learn-english.com/the-verb-is-as-an-action-verb.html)

Comment: But while "only one call away" is indeed a how (which adverbs do often answer), so do adjectives.  And the idea of "am" being an action here, (or almost anywhere) seems a real stretch.  It isn't something you're actively doing.  So I'm quite confident it is SVCC